# Why am I only getting a few functions when I'm importing rxjs/Rx

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, angular2-template, rxjs5

I am importing like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs' ;
```

or

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx' ;
```

And declared a property like this

```
ob : Observable<any>;
```

When I write `this.ob.fromarray()` in my constructor I'm only getting IntelliSense for `subscribe` and 2 or 3 other functions, not `fromarray` which is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to import the whole ReactiveXJS package like this:

```js
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

On the other hand `Observable.fromArray(arr: Array<any>)` is a static method - you can't use it on an instance. The documentation though says, that this method is deprecated and one should use `Observable.from()` now.

Use it like so for instance:

```js
//our root app component
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of output">{{item}}</div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  ob: Observable<any>;

  someArray: Array<number> = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ];
  output: Array<number> = [];

  constructor() {
    this.ob = Observable.from(this.someArray);

    this.ob.subscribe((data) => {
      this.output.push(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try it out - I'm using it the same way and it works in Visual Studio Code and in WebStorm aswell.

Comment: im using visual code studio i need to do like this Observable.fromArray

Comment: `Observable.fromArray(arr: Array<any>)` is a static method - you can't use it on an instance

Comment: Check the docs: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/from.md

Comment: How can i import, Rx because if im doing import { Rx } from 'rxjs/Rx' ; or rxjs this gives red line under { Rx }

Comment: You don't need to prefix it with `Rx`. Just do it like I showed it in the answer.

Comment: How can I? If im doing in the component class like this rx : Rx, its saying can not find Rx

Comment: Don't. Use. Rx. - Have your observable member `ob: Observable<Array<Any>>;` and in your constructor you instantiate it: `this.ob = Observable.from(PUT_AN_ARRAY_HERE);`

Comment: yes I have tried it but there is no Observable.from

Comment: one more thing that I have not installed rx https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx im using what already in package.json, does it make any difference

Comment: Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rPNaFO077499s8nYn0xQ?p=preview) - the `src/app.ts`. And no, you don't need a seperate package.

Comment: are you using with rc4?

Comment: Im still unable to get method "from" on Observable

Comment: *"the whole ReactJS package"* it's not reactjs.

Comment: I delete node module folder and reinstall all depedencies now i can get Rx please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158298/angular2-why-array-push-is-not-working/38159140#38159140

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the operators seperatly like this:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

import "rxjs/add/observable/interval";
import "rxjs/add/operator/take";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/bufferCount"
```

[check this for example](https://gist.github.com/MichalZalecki/d78c52ec55d7ec7b53f7)

And I think that fromarray() is deprecated. Use from() instead.
I hope this can help you.

Comment: Imports are not the actual problem here.